# Убрать элемент из Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

У меня есть два спинера которые заполнены одинаковыми данными. Задача состоит в том, что бы в случае выбора элемента в первом спинере, во втором он не отображался. Для этого использовал кастомный адаптер:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private int hidingItemIndex;

CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects, int hidingItemIndex) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.hidingItemIndex = hidingItemIndex;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    if (position == hidingItemIndex) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setHeight(0);
        tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        v = tv;
    } else {
        v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
    }
    return v;
}

}
```

И его использование:

```
final CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currencyList, hidingItemIndex);   
    customAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(customAdapter);

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (parent.getId()) {
                    case R.id.spinner:

                    hidingItemIndex = position;
                            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                          
                            // ...

                        break;
                    case R.id.spinner2:
                        // ...

                        break;
                }

        }
```

Все проверял. hidingItemIndex при выборе разных элементов в первом спинере изменяет значение, но второй спинер не изменяется (по умолчанию hidingItemIndex = 0 и остается прежним).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код не работает, потому что примитивные типы в Java передаются по значению а не по ссылке. То есть в конструктор адаптера попадает значение переменной `hidingItemIndex` и никакие дальнейшие её изменения не оказывают влияния на это значение. Вам нужно добавить к адаптеру метод, который будет менять переменную внутри него и вызывать этот метод:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int hidingItemIndex;
    ...
    public void setHiddenItemIndex(int index) {
        hidingItemIndex = index;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

И его использование:

```
customAdapter.setHiddenItemIndex(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если скрыть только один элемент,то можно сделать так

`if(position == hidingItemIndex){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_hint_list_item_layout, parent, false); 
        } else {`

spinner_hint_list_item_layout.xml представляет из себя пустой

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
```

Если они появляются по очереди, то во втором просто после выбора в лисенере присваивайте адаптер второму

```
            spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
            spinner1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(500);//для плавного появления
            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                  spinner2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(500);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

Но,опять же,это работает если выбор во втором зависит от первого